# How can I set the font-family of large titles on iOS?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

By attaching an event listener to the `loaded-event` on Page and getting the `NativeView-object` I've been able to set the `prefersLargeTitle` to true:

```
loaded(event){
  const page = event.object;

  if (isIOS) {
    page.frame.ios.controller.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true;
  }
}
```

This works, but I would like to change the font-family of the large title. How can I do this in Nativescript?

Comment: did you try `largeTitleTextAttributes`?

Comment: @Manoj no and I've been looking for documentation on it, but I can't find a good example on how to set it in Nativescript.

Comment: Try `.largeTitleTextAttributes = { [NSFontAttributeName]: Font.default.withFontFamily('fontFamily').withFontSize(fontSize).getUIFont(UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)) };`

Comment: I tried the following now after your suggestion: 

navbar.largeTitleTextAttributes = {[NSFontAttributeName]: Font.default.withFontFamily('New York').withFontSize(30).getUIFont(UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20))};

No effect, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the code below to your `app.js`

```
import {
    isIOS
} from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import {
    ActionBar
} from "tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar";
import {
    Font
} from "tns-core-modules/ui/styling/font";

if (isIOS) {
    ActionBar.prototype.originalSetColor = ActionBar.prototype.setColor;
    ActionBar.prototype.setColor = function (navBar, color) {
        ActionBar.prototype.originalSetColor.call(this, navBar, color);
        var newDict = {
            [NSFontAttributeName]: Font
                .default
                .withFontFamily(
                    "yourFontFamily")
                .withFontSize(yourFontSize)
                .getUIFont(UIFont
                    .systemFontOfSize(20)),
        };
        if (navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes) {
            newDict[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes.valueForKey(NSForegroundColorAttributeName);
        }
        navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = newDict;
    };
}
```

You may still set the `prefersLargeTitles` flags as you are doing already.